# Error processing your request: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have installed magento 1.9 CE on my local server and it was working fine. Suddenly it stopped working and shows error like

> There has been an Error processing your request.

When I check error report from report folder then I got logs like

```
a:5:{i:0;s:219:"Error in file: "C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\XmlConnect\sql\xmlconnect_setup\upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'xmlconnect_images' already exists";i:1;s:950:"
#0 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.0.1')
#2 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.6.0.0', '1.6.0.0.1')
#3 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\anzonline\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:11:"/anzonline/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/anzonline/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I have found several solutions from `Google` but none of those worked out for me [example](https://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/exception-printing-disabled-default-security-reasons-error-log-record-numb-11362/#.U1DeIVa-yrR).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Magento tries to create a table which already exists. This takes place in an upgrade script and was probably caused by an incomplete previous run of said upgrade script. Magento executes upgrade scripts, but only marks them done when they complete without error. Even an incompletely run script can have created tables, though, and next time Magento tries to run that update script the exstance of those tables cause a problem.

So you can either do some Database work and do some tweeking like removing the tables in question (with saving the data if needed), or you redo your Magento Installation.

This can also be caused by recently installed extensions, if so uninstalling them with the Connect Manager and reinstalling them might work.

Comment: But i did not find any tables which is showing in error like 'xmlconnect_images'

Answer (score 0):

Use

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xmlconnect_images;

then, refresh your brownser. It works for me.

You can clear cache if you dont see any changes:

To clear the cache, simply delete everything from the /var/cache directory and then reload your website in your browser.

> rm -rf magento/var/cache/*

To clear all sessions, you can also delete everything from the /var/session folder within your Magento installation directory.

> > rm -rf magento/var/session/*